# StaleElementException in Selenium python foreach loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I know this is not new error but i have gone through probably all the answers from StackExchange and StackOverflow on this topic and still i am unable to solve StaleElementException. I used implicit as well as explicit wait(See in comment of code). Please provide me solution and also please visit the site before answering the question so you will have the exact idea what i am going through. I want to get all the data from dropdown element(and yes also tried Select class). The issue here is StaleElementException.The problem is not with dropdown but the StaleElementException I can't seem to get rid of it.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Code :

```
`PinId = 'ctl00_Contentplaceholder2_ddlPin'
 RoadId = 'ctl00_Contentplaceholder2_ddlRoadName'
 BuildingId = 'ctl00_Contentplaceholder2_ddlBuildingName'
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 import time
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get('https://www.bestundertaking.net/BuildingWiseConsumerDetails.aspx')
 PinSelect = driver.find_element_by_id(PinId) # WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, PinId)))
 PinValues = [x for x in PinSelect.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
 try:
for p in PinValues:
    if p.get_attribute("value") is None or p.get_attribute("value") == '' or p.get_attribute("value") == ' ':
        continue
    PinSelect = driver.find_element_by_id(PinId)  # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, PinId)))
    PinSelect.send_keys(p.get_attribute("value"))
    driver.implicitly_wait(50)
    time.sleep(2)

    RoadValues = driver.find_element_by_id(RoadId)
    roadoptions = [x for x in RoadValues.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]  # Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, RoadId))))
    for o in roadoptions:
        if o.get_attribute("value") is None or o.get_attribute("value") == '' or o.get_attribute("value") == ' ':
            continue
        RoadSelect = driver.find_element_by_id(RoadId)  # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, RoadId)))
        RoadSelect.send_keys(o.get_attribute("value"))
        driver.implicitly_wait(50)
        time.sleep(2)

        BuildingValues = driver.find_element_by_id(BuildingId)
        buildoptions = [x for x in BuildingValues.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
        for b in buildoptions:
            if b.get_attribute("value") is None or b.get_attribute("value") == '' or b.get_attribute("value") == ' ':
                continue
            print(b.get_attribute("value"))
            ----> # The Error Occurs here. <----
            BuildingSelect = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, BuildingId)))
            BuildingSelect.send_keys(b.get_attribute("value"))

            # print(b.text)

 except StaleElementReferenceException:
    print('e')`
```

Comment: Point on line that is the cause of exception

Comment: Added comment where error occurs.